# MYSQL sum of costs for all employees for certain date

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to write a mysql query that will list all employees, their job function, and the total costs of all jobs they did for a particular day. Here is the relevant portion of my tables:

```
job_function table
emp_func
emp_num


employee table
emp_name
emp_num

job table
job_date
emp_num
job_name

job_type table
cost
job_name
```

The query works except that it is only returns the employees that had a job for that particular day. If an employee had no job that day they do not show up. I need to to display all employees, even those that had no job that day. Any suggestions on how to do that? Here is my query:

```
SELECT
employee.emp_name,
job_function,emp_func,
SUM(job_type.cost)
FROM
employee
INNER JOIN job ON job.emp_num = employee.emp_num
INNER JOIN job_function ON job_function.emp_num = employee.emp_num
INNER JOIN job_type ON job.job_name = job_type.job_name
where job_date = '2016-04-16'
group by emp_name;
```

Comment: you should find your answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: Is there anything more I need to change or it is just the join? I thought it might be a joining issue but I tried a few others and it didn't get me any closer. `FULL OUTER JOIN` doesn't seem to work with MYSQL either, at least not in the way I am using it.

Comment: It's also a bit confusing as I am joining 4 tables instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `left join` to get results even if there are no rows in the left joined table that fit the `on`-condition; the values in columns of the left joined tables are returned as `null` in such cases.

You also need to move your `where`-condition to the `on`-condition; your `where` would otherwise require the date in the `job`-table to be `2016-04-16`, so it has to exist (and not be `null`), which would make the `left join` behave like a `join` again.

```
SELECT 
  employee.emp_name,
  job_function.emp_func,
  SUM(job_type.cost)
FROM employee
JOIN job_function ON job_function.emp_num = employee.emp_num
left JOIN job ON job.emp_num = employee.emp_num and job.job_date = '2016-04-16'    
left JOIN job_type ON job.job_name = job_type.job_name
group by employee.emp_name, job_function.emp_func;
```

I also fixed your `group by` and added the `emp_func`-column there, since you select that column. This would otherwise result in an error in MySQL 5.7+ with default settings, and otherwise might give you wrong results in cases where an employee has more than one function.

Comment: Ah, that is very helpful thank you. I did not think about using an `AND` on a join.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `job_date = '2016-04-16'` you can see only the employees that work in that day, you should remove WHERE to see all the employees or put an interval like `job_date>'2016-04-16' AND job_date<'2016-05-31'`

Comment: Right, but I need the date. I realize the `where` clause is excluding those employees but I need to figure out how to include those employees and keep the date. That's just as close as I have gotten. It should show ALL employees and the total costs of their jobs for that day. If there are no jobs for an employee that day, it should show a sum of 0, instead of not including the employee altogether.

Comment: Wow, i'm thinking about your problem since 10 minutes without find a solution, it's a little bit difficul 

Comment: Lol, glad it's not just me.

Comment: Maybe i've got a solution, you should include all attributes without 'WHERE' but you should modifier a SUM() with a condition here